# Update a variable from a function that is persistent (python3 and tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, registry

How would one go about either saving the results of a function as a global variable to be used in another function later, or to update the variable value as a result of the function being ran?

I am trying to record the file path from user input on a small tkinter gui python 3 app.

```
    def sw_click():      # User clicks button
        sw_path1 tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/')  
        softwareP_label.config(text=sw_path1)
        print(sw_path1)     #  Just for logging
        return sw_path1
```

Attempting to use a global variable outside of the function, the value of the varaible is always none or "".

```
    sw_path1 = None    # Or using "" has same results

    def software_click():
        global sw_path11
        tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/')
        return sw_path1
```

Using a simple print command to check the variable values, a print of the variable was done at executing and value was None or "".  Running the function with **print** included, prints the correct path of the variable I was trying to get.  Printing the variable after the function has been ran, the value is back to None or ""

The None's return error, "NameError: name 'sw_path1' is not defined"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling error: the variable is called `sw_path11` only in the functions global statement.

The you have to assign the return from filedialog to the variable `sw_path1`.

```
import tkinter.filedialog

sw_path1 = None    # Or using "" has same results

def software_click():
    global sw_path1
    sw_path1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/')
    return sw_path1

software_click()
print(sw_path1)
```

As you are assigning the return value to a golbal variable you don't really need to return it as well, although that would be more pythonic.

```
import tkinter.filedialog

sw_path1 = None    # Or using "" has same results

def software_click():
    return tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/')

sw_path1 = software_click()
print(sw_path1)
```

Comment: Original was lengthy, tried to cut it down and then paste, had a type.  That worked, I see there it is needs to be separated, I crammed it together. Thanks much